# input type number does not get focus and not set cursor

Tags: javascript, html

Any idea on how to get focus and cursor on input type number ?

`focus() and select()` does not work

Using html and plain javascript

Comment: try `addEventListener()`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, use `addEventListener()` to achieve the effect you want

```
    <input type="number" id="input" />

    <script>
    document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('focus', function() {
      console.log('input focus')
    })

    document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('select', function() {
      console.log('input select')
    })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed this issue in chrome (using select()).

I found this Mozilla website. It suggests this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select

> In browsers where it is not supported, it is possible to replace it
> with a call to HTMLInputElement.setSelectionRange() with parameters 0
> and the input's value length:

I haven't tested this with input type=number, but I believe it SHOULD work. Probably. Maybe :)

-- Edit --

I just tested this. It is working for me with focus()